# I want to downgrade Angular CLI globally as my project is using older version of it

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have upgraded my Angular CLI globally but my project is using an older version of angular CLI, so I want to downgrade my Angular CLI globally.

Comment: Overall, I think it would be nice to control which release of Angular 2 you want to use, especially since it has undergone so many changes prior to its official release.

Answer (score 57):

You can downgrade your global `angular-cli` installation to eg. `1.0.0-beta.14` by issuing:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.14
```

The complete upgrade/downgrade guide is on [GitHub README](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli).

Comment: this downloads the latest version for me, not the version I specify in the install command.

Comment: @Jim: I've tried the commands again, and it works - installed version is indeed `1.0.0-beta.14` according to `package.json` file. Did you really specify your desired version as `angular-cli@<version>`?

Comment: as of the latest version of NPM it will basically "heal" itself.  you have to run npm clean cache with the --force switch
** also you may just need to exit the terminal and reopen.  that has happened to me on win10 with gitbash.

Comment: @jogi This is so annoying I have uninstalled, cleaned cache with force flag and I keep getting the latest version installed after specifying that I want npm install -g @angular/cli@1.5.2

Comment: @kolexinfos - check that your package.json for the project in question is specifying this version specifically.  Having it installed globally doesn't mean it would be used for a project necessarily. if it is installed locally in your node_modules as the older (but newer) version it might still be using this one.  Please take this as a guess though w/o seeing it I can't know.  It definitely can be confusing, this is the worst thing about node/ng.  good luck...

Answer (score 51):

Just for folks seeing this in the future, nowadays angular cli is named @angular/cli on npm, so the new commands to downgrade are these:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.8 // or whatever version you need
```

Comment: Now, this should be the answer.

Comment: the `npm cache verify` is also a recommended option after `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`, being used as an alternative for `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 4):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.14
```

Comment: In my case, even after cleaning the cache, it always showed the latest angular CLI. After restarting the computer downgraded version appeared correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, this is how I resolve it.

- go to the terminal (outside your project)
- uninstall angular cli
  **npm uninstall -g @angular/cli**
- install the version you need
  **npm install -g @angular/cli@10.2.1**
- go to you project and install again angular cli
  **npm install @angular/cli@10.2.1 --force**
- verify you have the correct version
  **ng version**