# I am stuck on Angular 8 Beta. How do i downgrade/uninstall to the stock/global Angular?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular7

I've just upgraded to Angular 8 beta. 
Followed this website: https://medium.com/@jeroenouw/upgrade-to-angular-8-beta-within-10-minutes-cd831fb8dd0e

I want to get back into the normal Angular 7.

I've tried to uninstall and install the latest Angular Cli by using these commands:

```
npm uninstall -g angular/cli

then

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

it says : 
"+ @angular/cli@7.3.8
added 295 packages from 180 contributors in 10.152s"

but when i do ng v, it still shows that I'm on Angular 8 Beta.

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.0.0-rc.2
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.800.0-rc.2
@angular-devkit/core         8.0.0-rc.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.0.0-rc.2
@schematics/angular          8.0.0-rc.2
@schematics/update           0.800.0-rc.2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to downgrade Angular CLI globally as my project is using older version of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826902/i-want-to-downgrade-angular-cli-globally-as-my-project-is-using-older-version-of)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command step by step

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: his is what i did and got back. "C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing."

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not cleared the cache.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: When i run the cache clean code. It returns: "C:\Windows\System32>npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
"

Answer (score 0):

If you can tell me the operating system you are using I can help with this one.
Generally(Windows):

1. `npm uninstall -g angular-cli
    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
    npm cache clean or npm cache clean --force`
2. goto : C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
3. Delete angular and @angular directories.
4. go back to C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm-cache and delete the _logs, _locks and _ccache directories.

You are good to go and reinstall a particular cversion of Angular by command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli [i.e. version 7.2.4 on 3rd may, 2019]
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest [for latest beta versions]
npm install -g @angular/cli@x.x.x [for your desired version here x=number]
```

Thanks, Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Windows 10.

Followed all the steps, still Angular 8

Comment: Can you share with me the angular version without reinstalling Angular again. ?
lets dig into it step by step.

Comment: Its already in the post. Or what do you mean by "angular version without reinstalling Angular again."?